# Selenium Webdriver Javascript - Typing french with sendKeys

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently I'm filling in a textbox with text using selenium to run my javascript code and I use the `sendKeys()` command to fill in text boxes. These scripts are ran in IE

code example: `element(by.id("htmlID")).sendkeys("my text here");`

My issue is when I try using `sendKeys()` to type french letters that has accents. it shows up as a black diamond shape instead. I've tried installing language packs and changing the layout of my computer to french but to no avail.

Is there a way I can use `sendKeys()` to type french accented characters?

Comment: Could you include a code snippet with the accented characters you are trying to send? There are many ways to encode non-ascii characters, so it would be nice to know which method you are using.

Comment: Additionally, the version of `IEDriverServer.exe` you're using will be of paramount importance. There are a number of changes that have been made in the area of non-ASCII characters that might be applicable, depending on the version.